# Showing Child Row on Changing Datasource

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatables

uses: -DataTables 1.10.12; ASP.NET;

Greetings!

This tool is great! I have being enjoying this ever since I found it.

I have been facing some difficulties with Child Rows. Pls. guide me on this. Appreciate if anybody could share their solutions.

**My Problem: Child row displaying on changing data sets:**

I have been getting error

> ctx[0].aoData[this[0]] is undefined

when I tried to get the child row after the datasource have been changed. New datasource is taken after a button click by passing parameters. Initial loading of data proves no problem but subsequent data loading gives the error. The error is passed as soon as the debugger hits the following code:

```
if (row.child.isShown()) {}
```

Below is my entire code:

```
function organization_GetAccountManagerDetailEarnings(purl, pstart, pend, pcontext, purl2) {

    var table;
    var existing_table = $('#accountManagerEarningsDataTable').dataTable();
    if (existing_table != undefined) {
        existing_table.fnClearTable();
        existing_table.fnDestroy();
    }

    table = $('#accountManagerEarningsDataTable').DataTable({
                        ajax: {
                            url: purl,
                            dataSrc: "",
                            data: function (d) {
                                d.from = pstart;
                                d.to = pend;
                                d.context = pcontext;
                            }
                        },
                        searching: false,
                        processing: true,
                        paging: false,
                        columnDefs:
                        [
                            {
                                className: "dt-right",
                                "targets": [2]
                            },
                            {
                                className: "dt-right",
                                "targets": [3]
                            },
                            {
                                className: "dt-right",
                                "targets": [4]
                            },
                            {
                                className: "dt-right",
                                "targets": [5]
                            },
                            {
                                className: "dt-right",
                                "targets": [6]
                            }
                        ],
                        columns: [
                            {
                                "className": 'details-control',
                                "orderable": false,
                                "data": null,
                                "defaultContent": ''
                            },
                            { "data": "AccountManagerName" },
                            { "data": "TradeCount" },
                            { "data": "SelfServiceTradeCount" },
                            { "data": "TotalDirectBrokerageValue" },
                            { "data": "TotalSelfServiceBrokerageValue" },
                            { "data": "TotalRetailBrokerageValue" }
                        ],
                        "order": [[4, 'desc']],
                        "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
                            var api = this.api(),
                            data;

                            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                            var intVal = function (i) {
                                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                                typeof i === 'number' ?
                                    i : 0;
                            };

                            // Total over all pages
                            total = api
                                .column(4)
                                .data()
                                .reduce(function (a, b) {
                                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                                }, 0);

                            // Total over this page
                            pageTotal = api
                                .column(4, {
                                    page: 'current'
                                })
                                .data()
                                .reduce(function (a, b) {
                                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                                }, 0);

                            // Update footer
                            $(api.column(4).footer()).html(
                                'LKR' + currencyFormat(pageTotal) + ' ( LKR' + currencyFormat(total) + ' total)');
                        }
    });

    $('#accountManagerEarningsDataTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {

        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);

        try {
            if (row.child.isShown()) {
                // This row is already open - close it
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            }
            else {
                $('div#collapseAccountManagerEarningsBody').block({
                    message: '<label>Processing</label>',
                    css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }
                });

                // Open this row
                var arrForTable1 = [];
                var arrForTable2 = [];

                totalBrokerage = 0;
                totalRetailBrokerage = 0;
                totalSelfServiceBrokerage = 0;

                console.log('You selected: ' + row.data().AccountManagerID);



                //problems with asynchoronus call back
                var response = organization_GetAccountManagerDetailEarningsAccountData(row.data(), purl2, pcontext);

                if (response.success === "true") {
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.value.length; i++) {

                        for (var j = 0; j < response.value[i].Securities.length; j++) {

                            var itemRow2 = {};
                            itemRow2["Security ID"] = response.value[i].Securities[j].SecurityId;
                            itemRow2["Trades"] = response.value[i].Securities[j].Trades;
                            itemRow2["Buy Qty"] = response.value[i].Securities[j].BuyQuantity;
                            itemRow2["Sell Qty"] = response.value[i].Securities[j].SellQuantity;
                            itemRow2["Total Brkg"] = response.value[i].Securities[j].Effective_Brokerage;
                            itemRow2["Online Brkg"] = response.value[i].Securities[j].Online_Brokerage;
                            arrForTable2.push(itemRow2);

                            totalBrokerage = totalBrokerage + parseFloat(response.value[i].Securities[j].Effective_Brokerage);
                            totalSelfServiceBrokerage = totalSelfServiceBrokerage + parseFloat(response.value[i].Securities[j].Online_Brokerage);
                        }

                        totalBrokerage = Math.round(totalBrokerage * 100) / 100;
                        totalSelfServiceBrokerage = Math.round(totalSelfServiceBrokerage * 100) / 100;
                        totalRetailBrokerage = Math.round(totalRetailBrokerage * 100) / 100;

                        var itemRow1 = {};
                        itemRow1["Account ID"] = response.value[i].AccountId;
                        itemRow1["Account Name"] = response.value[i].AccountName;
                        itemRow1["..."] = '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">' + buildHtmlTable(arrForTable2, 'table2x' + j) + '<p>Total Brokerage ' + numberWithCommas(totalBrokerage) + '</p></div>';
                        arrForTable1.push(itemRow1);
                        arrForTable2 = [];

                        totalBrokerage = 0;
                        totalRetailBrokerage = 0;
                        totalSelfServiceBrokerage = 0;

                    }

                    htmlTable1 = buildHtmlTable(arrForTable1, 'table1x' + i);
                    //console.log("2. " + JSON.stringify(htmlTable1));
                    row.child(htmlTable1).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                }
                else {
                    row.child('<table><tr><td>' + response.value[0].AccountId + '</td></tr></table>').show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                };

                $('div#collapseAccountManagerEarningsBody').unblock();
            }
        } catch (e) {

            console.log(e.message);
            $('div#collapseAccountManagerEarningsBody').unblock();
        }

    });
}

function organization_GetAccountManagerDetailEarningsAccountData(d, purl2, context) {

    var result = null;

    $.ajax({
        url: purl2,
        data: { "pAccountManagerId": d.AccountManagerID, "pFromDate": d.StartDate, "pToDate": d.EndDate, "pContext": context },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            result = data;
        }
    });



    return result;

}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="collapse" id="collapseAccountManagerEarnings">
    <div class="well">
        <div id="collapseAccountManagerEarningsBody">
            <!--<img src="~/Images/loading.gif" />-->
            <table id="accountManagerEarningsDataTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>A/c Manager</th>
                        <th>Trades</th>
                        <th>Self Service Trades</th>
                        <th>Effective Brokerage</th>
                        <th>Self Service Brokerage</th>
                        <th>Retail Brokerage</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:right" colspan="5">Total:</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this happens in mozilla but not in chrome

Answer (score 1):

I would have just written this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation. So...

It looks to me as though your jQuery selector `$('#accountManagerEarningsDataTable tbody')` may not exist after you change the datasource. Are your 100% certain that the table is rendered with a `<tbody>` element when the datasource is changed? I noticed your example HTML does not have a `<tbody>` element in the `#accountManagerEearningsDataTable` so the selector would be undefined.

Comment: Thank you for the time in writing to helping me. I have the `<tbody>` tag in the **#accountManagerEarningsDataTable** I don't know whether after the datasource changed the `<tbody>` disappears which I may have to revert back after debugging the browser.